# django 1.3 delete model instance and delete file

Tags: django, file, model, instance, delete-file

I am trying to overriding a Django model's delete method like this

```
class Picture(models.Model):

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/')
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.image)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.image.delete()
        super(Picture, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

but nothing happen why? The picture file is always in the photos' folder. I am using django 1.3

Answer (score 2):

Django doesn't delete files any more from [version 1.3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/releases/1.3/#deleting-a-model-doesn-t-delete-associated-files)

> In earlier Django versions, when a model instance containing a
>   FileField was deleted, FileField took it upon itself to also delete
>   the file from the backend storage. This opened the door to several
>   data-loss scenarios, including rolled-back transactions and fields on
>   different models referencing the same file. In Django 1.3, when a
>   model is deleted the FileField's delete() method won't be called. If
>   you need cleanup of orphaned files, you'll need to handle it yourself
>   (for instance, with a custom management command that can be run
>   manually or scheduled to run periodically via e.g. cron).

Answer (score 1):

You can use either a cronjob or a manual command to delete orphan files. Alternatively you could use a [post_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/signals/#post-delete) handler to remove the file. This would have the advantage, that the code is only executed, when the transaction that deleted the model instance succeeded.

Note however, that post_delete handlers are only run on Model.delete(), not on QuerSet.delete(). This was fixed in the current dev version of Django, so if you regulary use QuerySet.delete() I would recommend using the dev version.

Answer (score 1):

There is simple solution - [django-cleanup](https://github.com/un1t/django-cleanup)

```
pip install django-cleanup
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
     ...
    'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig',
)
```